# Assertions in ABAP

Tags: abap, assert

Over the years I've written code in a variety of languages and environments, but one constant seemed to be the consensus on the use of assertions. As I understand it, they are there for the development process when you want to identify "impossible" errors and other situations to which your first reaction would be "that can't be right" and which cannot be handled gracefully, leaving the system in a state where it has no choice but to terminate. Assertions are easy to understand and quick to code but due to their fail-fast nature are unsuitable for development code. Ideally, assertions are used to discover all development bugs and then removed or turned off when shipping the code. Input or program states that are wrong, but possible (and expected to occur) should instead be handled gracefully via exceptions or other error handling techniques.

However, none of this seems to hold true for writing ABAP code for SAP. I've just spent the better part of an hour trying to track down the precise location where an assert was giving me an unintelligible error. This turned out to be five levels down in standard SAP code, which is apparently riddled with `ASSERT` statements. I now know that a certain variable identifying a table `IS NOT INITIAL` while its accompanying variable identifying a field is.

This tells me nothing. The Web Dynpro component running this code actually "catches" this assert, showing me a generic error message, which only serves to prevent the debugger from launching when the assert is tripped.

My question therefore is what the guidelines or best practices are for the use of assertions in ABAP. Is this SAP writing bad code? Is it an accepted practice to fill your custom code with asserts and leave them in when shipping the code? If so, how would we go about handling these asserts in runtime so that the application doesn't crash and burn while still being able to identify the cause of the error?

Comment: I don't really have an answer on the use of assert (I only use it in dev to force test error conditions) but I can tell you that SAP writes bad code all the time.  I would not be surprised at all to find that they had done so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The guidelines and best practices are virtually the same in ABAP development as in any other language. Assertion should be used as internal guidance checks only, exceptions for regular input validation errors and other stuff. It might be sensible to leave the assertions in the code - after all, you'd probably rather want your program to crash in a controlled fashion than continue in an unforeseen way and probably damage some critical data in the process without anyone noticing. Take a look at [checkpoint groups](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapassert.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@) if you don't want your program to abort in a production environment - but in my opinion: What's the use of a sanity check (as a last line of defense) if it's disabled in the environment where it matters most?

Of course I'm assuming that the input is validated properly (so that crashes are prevented) and that all APIs are used according to the intended use and documentation. Unfortunately - as with every other programming language - it's up to the developer to live up to these standards.

Comment: I support that point of view. Unless you happen to be the 1st one to encounter this error situation, searching for the assertion in SAP notes is a quick way to find the solution for the problem. Much easier than trying to fix corrupted data later.